# Scrape data from list of websites

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

`I'm trying to scrape data such as

**Date of Incorporation, Email Address,Address and Director Details** 
From a list of 500 websites which is in https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list/nic-300-company.html which extends to many pages. I need to extract websites, which i have done using Power query in excel, but then to extract specific details from each website is a tedious work in Power Query.

Also,the issue lies in the Email Address and Address, unable to find a class/tag ID name.(This i have got recently , but now i need help with the huge chunk of websites, the code should work for all websites(since they have same type of data at specific places.

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const URL = "https://www.zaubacorp.com/company/TECHDRIVE-SOFTWARE-LIMITED/U30007DL1999PLC356280"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim elem As Object, adr As Object

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", URL, False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each elem In Html.getElementsByTagName("b")
        If InStr(elem.innerText, "Email ID:") > 0 Then
            [A2] = elem.ParentNode.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next elem

    For Each adr In Html.getElementsByTagName("b")
        If InStr(adr.innerText, "Address:") > 0 Then
            [B2] = adr.ParentNode.NextSibling.innerText
            Exit For
        End If
    Next adr
End Sub
```

Comment: Set webpage = ie.document
Set mtbl = webpage.getElementsByTagName("Table")(1)
Set table_data = mtbl.getElementsByTagName("tr")

this simple code i did for wikipedia to extract data, but for tabove particular website, it's not working plus i have 500+ websites spread across many pages.
Please have a look at the website before any suggestios.

Comment: Please don't post code in comments! Code in comments is unreadable and in most cases useless because line breaks are not visible but they matter a lot in VBA. Instead put all that belongs to your question into the original question part. You can [edit] it to put your code or addintional information.

Comment: @SIM As i explained you earlier as well, i couldn't vote your answer sir.
The question was closed.
i apologie again.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Done Sir, i have attached my initial small code

Comment: Well, you cannot post 3 lines of code and wait for us to finish your entire project (this is not a free code writing service). You didn't even tell what is wrong with the code. What is your issue with that code?

Comment: @SIM Okay sir, 
i do understand, i'll keep that in mind from next time.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes, i will try to add my code in this.
It's just that my previous question was closed and wanted to know why, so was taking help from oothers.

Comment: @AmitShah Questions in general get closed if you either: • didn't ask a proper question according to [ask]. • didn't show any effort to solve your issue on your on and even did not show what you have researched. • Or if your question is unclear and you did not provide enough details.  ••• All these 3 points applicable to your post here: • There is no question. • You did not show any effort or what you tried. • It is completely unclear what you want to achieve and what *"I need to find for multiple websites at a time in this scenario"* actually means. So I suggest to improve this by an [edit].

Comment: @SIM Noted Sir, will do it asap.
I was occupied with some other works as well.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Apologies, i'm new to this forum, will improve overtime.

Comment: @SIM Could you please check the question below, couldn't tag you there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've modified your existing script to traverse multiple pages which is now able to extract `name`,`Date of Incorporation`,`email` and `address` of each container from there. Make sure to create a sheet named `DataContainer` before executing the script below.

```
Sub GetInfo()
    Const prefix$ = "https://www.zaubacorp.com/company-list/nic-300/p-"
    Const suffix$ = "-company.html"
    Dim Html As New HTMLDocument, Htmldoc As New HTMLDocument
    Dim newHtml As New HTMLDocument, newUrl$, elem As Object, oDate As Object, R&, I&
    Dim Wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, adr As Object, P&, pageNum&

    Set Wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = Wb.Worksheets("DataContainer") '----------->create a sheet and name it `DataContainer` in order for the script to write the results in there

    For pageNum = 1 To 2  '---------------------------------> this is where you put the highest number the script will traverse
        With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
            .Open "GET", prefix & pageNum & suffix, False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        With Html.querySelectorAll("#table tbody tr")
            For I = 0 To .Length - 1
                Htmldoc.body.innerHTML = .item(I).outerHTML
                newUrl = Htmldoc.querySelector("a[href]").getAttribute("href")

                With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
                    .Open "GET", newUrl, False
                    .send
                    newHtml.body.innerHTML = .responseText
                End With

                R = R + 1: ws.Cells(R, 1) = newHtml.querySelector(".container > h1").innerText

                For Each oDate In newHtml.getElementsByTagName("p")
                    If InStr(oDate.innerText, "Date of Incorporation") > 0 Then
                        ws.Cells(R, 2) = oDate.ParentNode.NextSibling.innerText
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next oDate

                For Each elem In newHtml.getElementsByTagName("b")
                    If InStr(elem.innerText, "Email ID:") > 0 Then
                        ws.Cells(R, 3) = elem.ParentNode.innerText
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next elem

                For Each adr In newHtml.getElementsByTagName("b")
                    If InStr(adr.innerText, "Address:") > 0 Then
                        ws.Cells(R, 4) = adr.ParentNode.NextSibling.innerText
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next adr
            Next I
        End With
    Next pageNum
End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome Sir,

I will tweak in this code to get the "Date of Incorporation".
Thanks for your valuable time and help.
Apologies for past blunders once again.

Comment: Unable to extract the "Date of Incorporation" value from  the Inspection Tool.

Comment: Hi Sir, i'm unable to extract the "date of Incorporation" and "Activity " from the list now.
Could you please help me out.

Comment: Okay, I've already modified the script to include the `date of Incorporation` @Amit Shah. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot,  i have tweaked the code for scraping more piece of info.